# create 5 minutes time series using random data

Tags: r, time-series

It is the first time I ask a question, so forgive me if I make any mistakes.

I want to create a dataset of 50 artificial time series samples every 5 minutes in R. I will use 5 minutes data for January 2017.

The R code I have used is:

```
consumption<- ts(matrix(rnorm(8928),8928,1),start=(2017),frequency=8928)
consumption
```

I use 8928 since a month with 31 days contains 8928 5-minutes intervals. I then try to replicate 50 time series samples.

```
consumption1 <- replicate(50,list(data[sample(nrow(consumption),replace=TRUE),]))
```

However, I get:

```
Error in `[.default`(data, sample(nrow(consumption), replace = TRUE), ) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone know how I can make my code efficient? It seems that I create large data sets when replicating 50 times.

Comment: shouldnt `data` be `consumption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` doesn't exist:

```
consumption1 <- replicate(50,list(consumption[sample(nrow(consumption),replace=TRUE),]))
```